# Mockito - Verify recursive methods

Tags: java, testing, recursion, mockito, verify

I have a method, which is recursive:

For example,

```
public static int myMethod(int index, int number) {
    if (index<4){
        index = index + number;
        return myMethod(index, number+1);
    }
    return index;
}
```

Now this is just a basic example. When I now want to test, how can I verify with Mockito, how many times the method gets called, because the parameters change?

Verify `(myMethod(1,2)).times(3)` would not work, because it only gets called once, then 1,2 will change.

Comment: That's quite weird question. Unit tests should test behaviour, not particular implementation. Just suppose that a unit test is just another use of the code as any other place you want to use the method from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could help but won't verify if the method was invoked with correct arguments:

```
Mockito.verify(myMethod(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt()), Mockito.times(3));
```